# Сохранить и вернуть сохраненные значения

Tags: python, orm, django

Есть метод `save()`, который сохраняет экземпляр, если метод `get()`, который возвращает значения, а есть ли метод, чтобы сохранил и вернул сохраненные значения?

Если такого метода нет, то как мне сохранить значения, а потом сразу же их получить? Таблица содержит единственное уникально поле id, которое инкриментом заполняется, по нему нельзя `get()` делать, так как не знаем, с каким id нам сохранил `save()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метод save() сохраняет объект и дальше с этим объектом можно работать.

```
>>> b2 = Blog(name='Cheddar Talk', tagline='Thoughts on cheese.')
>>> b2.id     # Returns None, because b doesn't have an ID yet.
>>> b2.save()
>>> b2.id     # Returns the ID of your new object.
```

[Источник](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save)

Comment: О, спасибо, то что нужно.